# Chromium build with ninja failed in ubuntu22.04

Tags: chromium, ninja, gn

follow [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/linux/build_instructions.md), I build chromium in my ubuntu22.04. when i run `autoninja -C out/Default chrome`, it failed with the following ouptut:

```
ninja: Entering directory `out/Default'
[33073/48535] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/frame_connected_bluetooth_devices.o
FAILED: obj/content/browser/browser/frame_connected_bluetooth_devices.o 
../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -MMD -MF obj/content/browser/browser/frame_connected_bluetooth_devices.o.d -DDCHECK_ALWAYS_ON=1 -DUSE_UDEV -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_OZONE=1 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=1 -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=\"llvmorg-17-init-12166-g7586aeab-3\" -DCOMPONENT_BUILD -DCR_LIBCXX_REVISION=b272a1c128aae14ac6f77836a4df86dd353fd57e -DCR_SYSROOT_KEY=20230611T210420Z-2 -D_DEBUG -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DCONTENT_IMPLEMENTATION -DV8_USE_EXTERNAL_STARTUP_DATA -DATK_LIB_DIR=\"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu\" -DUSE_ATK_BRIDGE -DATSPI_MAJOR_VERSION=2 -DATSPI_MINOR_VERSION=44 -DATSPI_MICRO_VERSION=1 -DGLIB_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED=GLIB_VERSION_2_56 -DGLIB_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=GLIB_VERSION_2_56 -DBASE_USE_PERFETTO_CLIENT_LIBRARY=1 -DWEBP_EXTERN=extern -DUSE_EGL -DVK_USE_PLATFORM_XCB_KHR -DVK_USE_PLATFORM_WAYLAND_KHR -DLIBYUV_DISABLE_NEON -DABSL_CONSUME_DLL -DBORINGSSL_SHARED_LIBRARY -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 -DU_ENABLE_DYLOAD=0 -DUSE_CHROMIUM_ICU=1 -DU_ENABLE_TRACING=1 -DU_ENABLE_RESOURCE_TRACING=0 -DICU_UTIL_DATA_IMPL=ICU_UTIL_DATA_FILE -DSK_ENABLE_SKSL -DSK_UNTIL_CRBUG_1187654_IS_FIXED -DSK_USER_CONFIG_HEADER=\"../../skia/config/SkUserConfig.h\" -DSK_WIN_FONTMGR_NO_SIMULATIONS -DSK_DISABLE_LEGACY_SKSURFACE_METHODS -DSK_DISABLE_LEGACY_GRAPHITE_IMAGE_FACTORIES -DSK_DISABLE_LEGACY_GRAPHITE_IMAGE_METHODS -DSK_DISABLE_LEGACY_SKSURFACE_FACTORIES -DSK_DISABLE_LEGACY_SKSURFACE_FLUSH -DSK_DISABLE_LEGACY_SKSURFACE_AS_IMAGE -DSK_DISABLE_LEGACY_SKSURFACE_DISPLAYLIST -DSK_CODEC_DECODES_JPEG -DSK_CODEC_DECODES_PNG -DSK_CODEC_DECODES_WEBP -DSK_ENCODE_JPEG -DSK_ENCODE_PNG -DSK_ENCODE_WEBP -DSK_HAS_WUFFS_LIBRARY -DSKIA_DLL -DSKCMS_API=__attribute__\(\(visibility\(\"default\"\)\)\) -DSK_GANESH -DSK_GPU_WORKAROUNDS_HEADER=\"gpu/config/gpu_driver_bug_workaround_autogen.h\" -DSK_GL -DSK_VULKAN=1 -DSK_GRAPHITE -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_STATIC_INITIALIZER -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_INTERNAL_DONATE_STEAL_INLINE=0 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DPROTOBUF_USE_DLLS -DLEVELDB_PLATFORM_CHROMIUM=1 -DLEVELDB_SHARED_LIBRARY -DCRASHPAD_ZLIB_SOURCE_EXTERNAL -DWEBRTC_ENABLE_SYMBOL_EXPORT -DWEBRTC_ENABLE_AVX2 -DWEBRTC_NON_STATIC_TRACE_EVENT_HANDLERS=0 -DWEBRTC_CHROMIUM_BUILD -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DWEBRTC_LINUX -DABSL_ALLOCATOR_NOTHROW=1 -DWEBRTC_USE_X11 -DWEBRTC_USE_PIPEWIRE -DWEBRTC_USE_GIO -DLOGGING_INSIDE_WEBRTC -DUSING_V8_SHARED -DV8_ENABLE_CHECKS -DV8_COMPRESS_POINTERS -DV8_COMPRESS_POINTERS_IN_SHARED_CAGE -DV8_31BIT_SMIS_ON_64BIT_ARCH -DV8_ENABLE_SANDBOX -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DV8_USE_PERFETTO -DCPPGC_CAGED_HEAP -DCPPGC_YOUNG_GENERATION -DCPPGC_POINTER_COMPRESSION -DCPPGC_SLIM_WRITE_BARRIER -DLIBGAV1_MAX_BITDEPTH=10 -DLIBGAV1_THREADPOOL_USE_STD_MUTEX -DLIBGAV1_ENABLE_LOGGING=0 -DLIBGAV1_PUBLIC= -DVK_NO_PROTOTYPES -DUSE_VULKAN_XCB -DSQLITE_OMIT_ANALYZE -DSQLITE_OMIT_AUTOINIT -DSQLITE_OMIT_AUTOMATIC_INDEX -DSQLITE_OMIT_AUTORESET -DSQLITE_OMIT_COMPILEOPTION_DIAGS -DSQLITE_OMIT_EXPLAIN -DSQLITE_OMIT_GET_TABLE -DSQLITE_OMIT_INTROSPECTION_PRAGMAS -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_LOOKASIDE=0,0 -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOOKASIDE -DSQLITE_OMIT_TCL_VARIABLE -DSQLITE_OMIT_REINDEX -DSQLITE_OMIT_TRACE -DSQLITE_OMIT_UPSERT -DSQLITE_OMIT_WINDOWFUNC -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DSQLITE_DISABLE_FTS3_UNICODE -DSQLITE_DISABLE_FTS4_DEFERRED -DSQLITE_ENABLE_ICU -DSQLITE_SECURE_DELETE -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_MAX_WORKER_THREADS=0 -DSQLITE_MAX_MMAP_SIZE=268435456 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_FILE_PERMISSIONS=0600 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_LOCKING_MODE=1 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_MEMSTATUS=1 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE=4096 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_PCACHE_INITSZ=0 -DSQLITE_LIKE_DOESNT_MATCH_BLOBS -DSQLITE_OMIT_DEPRECATED -DSQLITE_OMIT_PROGRESS_CALLBACK -DSQLITE_OMIT_SHARED_CACHE -DSQLITE_USE_ALLOCA -DSQLITE_OMIT_DECLTYPE -DSQLITE_OMIT_JSON -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION -DSQLITE_HAVE_ISNAN -DSQLITE_HAVE_SQLITE3R -DSQLITE_ENABLE_DBPAGE_VTAB -DSQLITE_ENABLE_BATCH_ATOMIC_WRITE -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOCKING_STYLE=0 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_API_ARMOR -I../.. -Igen -I../../buildtools/third_party/libc++ -I../../third_party/perfetto/include -Igen/third_party/perfetto/build_config -Igen/third_party/perfetto -I../../third_party/libwebp/src/src -I../../third_party/khronos -I../../gpu -I../../third_party/vulkan-deps/vulkan-headers/src/include -I../../third_party/wayland/src/src -I../../third_party/wayland/include/src -Igen/third_party/dawn/include -I../../third_party/dawn/include -I../../third_party/libyuv/include -I../../third_party/jsoncpp/source/include -Igen/third_party/private_membership/src -Igen/third_party/shell-encryption/src -Igen/components/policy/proto -I../../third_party/abseil-cpp -I../../third_party/boringssl/src/include -I../../third_party/protobuf/src -Igen/protoc_out -I../../third_party/ipcz/include -I../../third_party/ced/src -I../../third_party/icu/source/common -I../../third_party/icu/source/i18n -I../../third_party/libwebm/source -I../../third_party/skia -Igen/third_party/skia -I../../third_party/wuffs/src/release/c -I../../third_party/vulkan/include -I../../third_party/mesa_headers -I../../third_party/leveldatabase -I../../third_party/leveldatabase/src -I../../third_party/leveldatabase/src/include -I../../third_party/crashpad/crashpad -I../../third_party/crashpad/crashpad/compat/linux -I../../third_party/crashpad/crashpad/compat/non_win -I../../third_party/zlib -I../../third_party/libaom/source/libaom -I../../net/third_party/quiche/overrides -I../../net/third_party/quiche/src/quiche/common/platform/default -I../../net/third_party/quiche/src -Igen/net/third_party/quiche/src -I../../third_party/webrtc_overrides -I../../third_party/webrtc -Igen/third_party/webrtc -Igen/third_party/metrics_proto -I../../v8/include -Igen/v8/include -I../../third_party/libgav1/src -I../../third_party/libgav1/src/src -I../../third_party/wayland/include -I../../third_party/wayland/src/cursor -I../../third_party/wayland/src/egl -Igen/third_party/wayland/src/protocol -I../../third_party/brotli/include -I../../third_party/distributed_point_functions -I../../third_party/distributed_point_functions/code -Igen/third_party/distributed_point_functions -I../../third_party/highway/src -I../../third_party/re2/src -I../../third_party/fontconfig/src -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wextra-semi -Wunreachable-code-aggressive -Wthread-safety -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-psabi -Wloop-analysis -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wenum-compare-conditional -Wno-ignored-pragma-optimize -Wno-deprecated-builtins -Wno-bitfield-constant-conversion -Wno-deprecated-this-capture -Wshadow -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -fno-ident -fno-strict-aliasing --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fPIC -pthread -fcolor-diagnostics -fmerge-all-constants -fcrash-diagnostics-dir=../../tools/clang/crashreports -mllvm -instcombine-lower-dbg-declare=0 -ffp-contract=off -fcomplete-member-pointers -m64 -msse3 -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__= -D__TIME__= -D__TIMESTAMP__= -ffile-compilation-dir=. -no-canonical-prefixes -ftrivial-auto-var-init=pattern -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -fvisibility=hidden -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang raw-ref-template-as-trivial-member -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-stack-allocated -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-ipc -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-raw-ptr-fields -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang raw-ptr-exclude-path=testing/platform_test.h -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang raw-ptr-exclude-path=sandbox/mac/ -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang raw-ptr-exclude-path=chrome/browser/ui/cocoa/touchbar/browser_window_default_touch_bar.mm -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang raw-ptr-exclude-path=device/bluetooth/test/mock_bluetooth_central_manager_mac.mm -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang raw-ptr-exclude-path=device/bluetooth/test/mock_bluetooth_cbperipheral_mac.mm -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang raw-ptr-exclude-path=ui/views/controls/native/native_view_host_mac_unittest.mm -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang raw-ptr-exclude-path=ui/views/widget/native_widget_mac_unittest.mm -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang raw-ptr-exclude-path=ui/views/controls/native/native_view_host_mac_unittest.mm -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang raw-ptr-exclude-path=um/winnt.h -Wheader-hygiene -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -Wexit-time-destructors -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/atk-1.0 -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/glib-2.0 -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/glib-2.0 -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/glib-2.0 -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/pango-1.0 -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/libmount -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/blkid -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/fribidi -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/harfbuzz -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/cairo -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/glib-2.0 -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/pixman-1 -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/uuid -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/libpng16 -Wno-redundant-parens -DPROTOBUF_ALLOW_DEPRECATED=1 -Wno-redundant-parens -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/nss -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/nspr -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/libdrm -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -isystem../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -Wno-undefined-bool-conversion -Wno-tautological-undefined-compare -std=c++20 -Wno-trigraphs -gsimple-template-names -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -nostdinc++ -isystem../../buildtools/third_party/libc++/trunk/include -isystem../../buildtools/third_party/libc++abi/trunk/include --sysroot=../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -c ../../content/browser/bluetooth/frame_connected_bluetooth_devices.cc -o obj/content/browser/browser/frame_connected_bluetooth_devices.o
Killed
[33090/48535] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/browser_interface_binders.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

It seems like there is something wrong with the bluetooth module and how to fix it

Comment: Looks like clang got terminated by an external process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your machine does not have enough memory for building chromium. Newer versions require memory intensively. I suggest having at least 16GB of RAM and 16GB or more of swap space.